# MongoDB get full doc after match, group, and sort

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Order:

```
{
  order_id: 1,
  order_time: ISODate(...),
  customer_id: 456,
  products: [
    {
      product_id: 1,
      product_name: "Pencil"
    },
    {
      product_id: 2,
      product_name: "Scissors"
    },
    {
      product_id: 3,
      product_name: "Tape"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a collection with a whole bunch of documents like the above. I would like to query for the latest order for each customer who ordered Scissors.

That is, where there exists a "products.product_name" which equals "Scissors", group by customer_id, give me the full document where the "order_time" is the "max" for that group.

To find the documents, I could do like `find({ 'products.product_name' : "Scissors" })` but then I get all of the order with Scissors, I only want the most recent.

So, I am looking at aggregation... Mongo's "$group" aggregation stage seems to require that you do some kind of actual aggregation inside like sum or max or whatever. I am guessing there's some combination of `$match`, `$group`, and `$sort` to use here but I can't seem to quite get it working.

Something close:

```
db.storcap.aggregate(
[
{
  $match: { 'products.product_name' : "Scissors" }
},
{
  $sort: { created_at:-1 }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$customer_id", 
  }
}]
)
```

But this doesn't return the full doc and I am not sure that it's doing the sorting and grouping right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/index.html) operator to get most recent order (are ordered desc) and special variable [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) to get whole object in a final result:

```
db.storcap.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 'products.product_name' : "Scissors" }
    },
    {
        $sort: { created_at:-1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$customer_id",
            lastOrder: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
])
```